# How to send a a notification to a specific endpoint using AWS SNS from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-sns

I have a Xamarin Forms app, for Android and iOS, which is using FirebasePushNotificationPlugin by CrossGeeks.

I am using Amazon SNS and Firebase for the messaging.

I can send messages to both the Android and iOS apps by using the Firebase console. I am now trying to code the send into a C# / ASP.Net website.

This is to send to a specific endpoint, rather than to a Topic.

What I'm not sure about is how to do that using Amazon SNS - AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient. Do I need to send specifically formatted JSON, or can I just send the message text and let Amazon sort it out?

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
PublishRequest pr = new PublishRequest
{
    Message = msgContent, 
    TargetArn = endPoint.Arn
};

PublishResponse resp = _client.Publish(pr);
```

msgContent would be something like "this is my message content". the endPoint.Arn is for a specific device.

It seems to send successfully but the notification message does not appear on the phone. Does the message actually need to be a JSON formatted string, rather than plain text?

I don't seem to be able to find any examples of how to do this. Plenty of examples of how to send messages from the Firebase console though

Answer (score 0):

I had a harder than expected time with this recently. The answer is that yes, the message needs to be specific json, AND the MessageStructure property needs to be set to json.

For Firebase in particular, seems like the message format has to be exact in order for the SNS-to-Firebase delivery to work.

Details are at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-custom-platform-specific-payloads-mobile-devices.html. The message format to replicate is

```
{
  "GCM":"{ \"notification\": { \"body\": \"Sample message for Android or iOS endpoints\", \"title\":\"TitleTest\" } }"
}
```

From C#, I did this by defining some classes that would serialize to the appropriate structure.

```
public class PushNotification
{
    [JsonProperty("body")]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public PushNotification(string title, string body)
    {
        Title = title;
        Body = body;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Firebase push notification.
/// </summary>
public class FCMPushNotification
{
    [JsonProperty("notification")]
    public PushNotification Notification { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }

    public FCMPushNotification()
    {
        Data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}

   public class SNSPushNotificationMessage
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Android specific content.
       /// </summary>
       [JsonProperty("GCM")]
       public string FCMContent { get; set; }
    
       public override string ToString()
       {
           return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
       }
   }
```

Then, to send, the code looks like this:

```
    var data = "Message to send";
    var message = new SNSPushNotificationMessage(data);

    message.FCMContent = new FCMPushNotification()
    {
        Notification = new PushNotification("Title", data),
        Data = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                { "time_to_live", "3600" }
        }
    }.ToString();

    var request = new PublishRequest()
    {
        TargetArn = _settings.TopicArn,
        Message = message.ToString(),
        MessageStructure = "json",
    };

    var response = await _snsClient.PublishAsync(request);
```